# Trying to show image in admin grid in custom module

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, image, grid, grid-serlization

What i was trying to do was to display thumbnail of images in listing in admin side in one of the custom modules created by me, at that time i came across this error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object in
>   D:\Program
>   Files\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php
>   on line 291.

Comment: Some code samples might help.

Comment: Then post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Even if you solved the problem, clarify your questions and post the solution please.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience...Answer to this is to check the path to render class in _prepareColumns() function in Grid.php.

For exmaple, In my case the path to the render class was wrong. Check the below code:

$this->addColumn('img', array(
            'header' => 'Image',
            'align' => 'left',
            'index' => 'img',
            'width'     => '70',
            'renderer' => 'demo/adminhtml_grid_renderer_img'
        ));

Here the renderer attribute holds the path to your render class, review it. IF the path is wrong at that time this type of error is shown.

Answer (score 7):

Open these file Grid php under app>code >core>Mage>Adminhtml>Block>Catalog >Product`and in`_prepareCollection`method add`$collection->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail');`just before`$this->setCollection($collection);`

add below code in method `_prepareColumns`

```
$this->addColumn('thumbnail',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Thumbnail'),
        'width' => '50px',
        'index' => 'thumbnail',
        'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_image')
));
```

After that add below method somewhere in the same file

```
public function callback_image($value)
{
    $width = 70;
    $height = 70;
    return "<img src='".Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/product'.$value."' width=".$width." height=".$height."/>";
}
```

thats all cheers. please override these changes if you know how to do that or else these changes will be wiped out during upgrade.

Comment: by just adding the correct path for render class in 'renderer' attrbute in $this->addColumn() will solve this issue

Comment: Or, don't hack the core!